# C FOpen() Open Documents Directory iOS

Tags: ios, c, fopen

I need help getting access to the documents directory using only C on iOS.

I have my .c file looking for a specific file in the application bundle.  I have no problem accessing this file.  It looks like this: fopen("*filename*",

Unfortunately, if I want to move that file to the documents directory, appending "/Documents/*filename*" doesn't work.

I know how to access the file using an objective-c class, easily, using filesystemrepresentation.  But I don't know how to do it only in C.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `fopen` treats the app bundle as the current directory, passing a path of `"Documents/filename"` should work. Note the lack of leading slash.

Comment: Turns out that passing the path of "Documents/filename" did not work, as you are in the directory that the executable file is in: ".app/".  I was able to get to the documents directory by making a char of the CWD and then removing the last couple characters of the char to get out of the ".app/" bundle and then appending the Documents path to the end of it.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Fopen defaults to the directory that the executable file is in, ".app/" - on iOS.

I was able to get to the documents directory by making a char of the Current Working Directory and then removing the last couple characters of the char to get out of the ".app/" bundle and then appending the Documents path to the end of it.